# Just short of being able to use inline css to replace :before and :after of stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I know that you cannot use :before or :after inline, and inline is all I can use for my email currently.

I have the following code I have used with a style sheet that works:

```css
    {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #progress {
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 12px;
      clear: both;
      line-height: 1em;
      margin: 0 -1px;
      text-align: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #progress li {
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 30px 10px 40px;
      background: #333;
      color: #fff;
      position: relative;
      border-top: 1px solid #666;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
      width: 10%;
      margin: 0 1px;
    }

    #progress li:before {
      content: '';
      border-left: 16px solid #fff;
      border-top: 16px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0; 
    }
    #progress li:after {
      content: '';
      border-left: 16px solid #333;
      border-top: 16px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      z-index: 20;
    }

    #progress li.completed {
      background: #369b2d;
    }

    #progress li.completed:after {
      border-left-color: #369b2d;
    }
    <ul id="progress" layout="row">
        <li class="completed">Submitted </li>
        <li>Reviewed</li>
        <li>Investigation</li>
        <li>Implementing</li>
        <li>Implemented</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

```html
    <ul id="progress" layout="row">
        <li class="completed">Submitted </li>
        <li>Reviewed</li>
        <li>Investigation</li>
        <li>Implementing</li>
        <li>Implemented</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I did my best to try and create a work around, but to be honest I am very new to trying to mess with css. I tried to do inline style, with a div inside the li for the before, and another for the after. The triangles I was trying to make showed up, but not in line with the text. If I try span, it is in line but the triangles are not right.

Example:

```
<li class="completed" style="float: left;padding: 10px 30px 10px 40px;background: #369b2d;color: #fff;position: relative;border-top: 1px solid #666;border-bottom: 1px solid #666;width: 10%;margin: 0 1px;"><span style = "border-left: 16px solid #fff; border-top: 16px solid transparent; border-bottom: 16px solid transparent; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 100%; z-index: 20; background: #369b2d;"> </span>Submitted <span style = "border-left: 16px solid #333; border-top: 16px solid transparent; border-bottom: 16px solid transparent; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background: #369b2d;"> </span></li>
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this inline code to match how it would look with the style sheet?

Comment: *"Does anyone know how I can fix this inline code to match how it would look with the style sheet?"* - stylesheets (files with *.CSS extension  doesn't look anything but text. It determines how html appears (presentation). Are you trying to ask this?: `*I have these particular rulesets in CSS that result in some arrows inline. I'd like to get the same results for email. Is this even possible?*`

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to communicate without knowing the proper vocabulary. Thank you for clarifying.